# sql injection in sql server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-injection

In my below procedure how can i check SQL injection for the parameters @TECHNOLOGY,@CURE,@APPLICATION?Please help

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SEARCH]
 @PRODUCTNAME NVARCHAR(500),
 @TECHNOLOGY NVARCHAR(200),
 @CURE NVARCHAR(200),
 @APPLICATION NVARCHAR(200)
AS
 SELECT DISTINCT PM.F_PRODUCT AS ID,
  PM.F_PRODUCT_NAME AS [NAME],
  PM.F_FORMAT AS FMT,
  PM.F_SUBFORMAT AS SFMT,
  STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + CAST(F_LANGUAGE AS VARCHAR(200)) FROM T_PDF_MSDS PD
    WHERE PD.F_PRODUCT = PM.F_PRODUCT AND PD.F_FORMAT = PM.F_FORMAT AND PD.F_SUBFORMAT = PM.F_SUBFORMAT
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS LANG,
  PM.F_DOC_PATH AS DPATH,
  CONVERT(VARCHAR,PM.F_PUBLISHED_DATE,120) AS PDATE,
  SUBSTRING(PM.F_CUSTOM1, CHARINDEX(':',PM.F_CUSTOM1)+1, LEN(PM.F_CUSTOM1)) AS TECHNOLOGY,
  SUBSTRING(PM.F_CUSTOM2, CHARINDEX(':',PM.F_CUSTOM2)+1, LEN(PM.F_CUSTOM2)) AS CURE,
  SUBSTRING(PM.F_CUSTOM3, CHARINDEX(':',PM.F_CUSTOM3)+1, LEN(PM.F_CUSTOM3)) AS [APPLICATION],
  'PDF' AS DOC
 FROM T_PDF_MSDS PM
 WHERE
  --(@PRODUCTNAME IS NULL OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PM.F_PRODUCT_NAME,'™','|TM'),'®','|TS'),'©','|CP'),'°','|DEG')
   --LIKE REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@PRODUCTNAME,'[','\['),'_','\_'),'™','|TM'),'®','|TS'),'©','|CP'),'°','|DEG') ESCAPE '\')
 (@TECHNOLOGY = '-1' OR PM.F_CUSTOM1 LIKE '%' + @TECHNOLOGY + '%')
  AND (@CURE = '-1' OR PM.F_CUSTOM2 LIKE '%' + @CURE + '%')
  AND (@APPLICATION = '-1' OR PM.F_CUSTOM3 LIKE '%' + @APPLICATION + '%')
  AND PM.F_AUTHORIZED IN (-1,1,3)
 GROUP BY PM.F_PRODUCT, PM.F_PRODUCT_NAME, PM.F_FORMAT, PM.F_SUBFORMAT, PM.F_DOC_PATH, PM.F_PUBLISHED_DATE, PM.F_CUSTOM1, PM.F_CUSTOM2, PM.F_CUSTOM3
;
```

is any sql injection is possible in above procedure?

Comment: See e.g. OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project): https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_SQL_Injection_(OTG-INPVAL-005). Your code seems safe because it does not use dynamically created SQL statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Injection is normally when the SQL command is built using unsanitised inputs. For instance...

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE MYCOLUMN = " + txtInput.Text;
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
...
```

By using a stored procedure as you have it, you are effectively protecting yourself from this.

---

Thanks to the comment by [@DanGuzman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3711162/dan-guzman) who points out that SQL Injection is indeed possible via stored procedure, should you call it in the wrong way...

```
var sql = "EXEC MySproc '" + txtInput.Text + "'";
var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql);
...
```

The correct way to do it would be to make sure you use a parameterised command, such as...

```
var cmd = new SqlCommand("MySproc", conn);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@MyParam", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200));
cmd.Parameters["@MyParam"].Value = txtInput.Text;
...
```

---

In response to the comment by the OP (which I feel is within the realms of the original question)...

It is also possible to be victim of SQL Injection through the use of Dynamic SQL within the stored procedure.  For example...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MySproc]
   @MyParam NVARCHAR(200),
   @MyParam2 INT
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
  SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyColumn] = ''' + @MyParam + N''''
  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
END
```

To protect yourself you should parameterise each variable that you're passing to the `sp_executesql`...

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyColumn] = @MyParamInner'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MyParamInner NVARCHAR(200)', @MyParam
```

*Note, you should NOT wrap the `@MyParamInner` with quotes on the where clause, even though it's a character-based variable*

If you have multiple values to pass through you'd update it to something like...

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(1000)
SET @SQL = N'SELECT * FROM [MyTable] WHERE [MyColumn] = @MyParamInner AND [MyColumn2] = @MyParam2Inner'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@MyParamInner NVARCHAR(200), @MyParam2Inner INT', @MyParam, @MyParam2
```

Comment: It is true that SQL injection within a stored procedure isn't possible unless there is dynamic SQL within the proc code. However, the application must still call the stored procedure correctly, using a parameterized command, to avoid risk of SQL injection.

Comment: @Dan, I'm intrigued to know how you could call a stored procedure without using parametrised command, or dynamic SQL, and achieve SQL injection?  (Honest question)

Comment: Fair question. `var sql = "EXEC dbo.YourProc '" + txtInput.Text + "';";`. I have seen proc calls built this way in a shared data access layer. Depending on the API, one can specify CommandType.StoredProcedure to ensure only the proc name is specified in the command text and parameters passed separately.

Comment: Fair answer!  May I add that to my answer?

Comment: I'm glad to see you improved your answer, and used strongly-typed parameters instead of `AddWithValue` too!

Comment: @Dan, absolutely... never liked anything (such as `AddWithValue`) which makes decisions on your behalf

Comment: SQL Injection is possible in Dynamic Sql stored procedure?.How to prevent it in Dyanmic SQL SP because we are using Dynamic SQL SP.

Comment: @Ram - yes, it is possible.  Normally I would suggest creating a new question, but I guess it is within the realms of your original. Will update my answer shortly

Comment: I created new question with dynamic SQL SP.